# Node headless (xvfb wrapper) spawning new displays

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

I'm programmatically creating virtual displays with headless, to be used with selenium tests

It doesn't work because headless keeps spawning displays with new ids, every time I run it. It works if before I start my test I run this with the display id I expect `headless` to generate

```
export DISPLAY=:[num]
```

It's obviously not reliable because if the program restarts it's going to use a new id.

I've tried passing a specific id like the headless docs show and it worked! But only the first time, haha

I don't see xvfb processes hanging after my node process quits.

I also tried node-xvfb with worse results.

I'll link to the libraries I used as soon as I get to a computer